# catch jquery ajax error in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe, offline

I have an html page with an iframe, and I want to catch errors happening inside the iframe (for example when am AJAX POST request can't be executed because I lost connection)

my code:

```
 <div id="mainContainer" style="width:100%">
        <iframe id="iframeid" src="http://something.com"></iframe>
 </div>
```

I tried things like:

```
document.getElementById("iframeid").contentWindow.onerror = function() {
   console.log("ajax error");
}
```

and

```
document.getElementById('iframeid').addEventListener('error', function() {
     console.log("ajax error");
});
```

I also tried

```
$('#iframeid').contents().ajaxError(function() {
     console.log("ajax error");
});
```

any help? thank you in advance

Comment: Is iframe  source from a different domain than the page it is displayed in?

Comment: yes it is from a different domain, maybe I should have mentioned that.

Comment: You can't access it unless you control code in both pages. This is part of *"same origin policy"* restrictions

Comment: I have access, I also tried with chrome --disable-web-security

Comment: *because I lost connection* if you lose connection, wouldn't that alert be from a local source (i.e. an error wouldn't come from a remote source if there's no connection).

Comment: All Ajax function are called from the client, so indeed the alert is javascript function called by the client.